# Python libraries not found even though available in the Project SDK Packages

Tags: python, intellij-idea

As shown in the following screenshot - `pyspark 2.2.0` is recognized within the `python 2.7.10 SDK`:

[image]

And the Intellij project is using that `python` sdk:

[image]

However, the interpreter is not "agreeing" with the sdk:

[image]

Furthermore the program can not be run:

Comment: In `Project` view, did you set `Project SDK`?

Comment: @Sraw Yes I neglected to take a screenshot of it though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following is more of a workaround then a real solution. For the `pyspark` libraries the only fix that has been working is to *manually* add the `zip` files for `py4j` and `pyspark` to the `python` global library ( `Project Structure | Global Libraries` )

[image]